# How to inject IHttpContextAccessor into Autofac TenantIdentificationStrategy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, multi-tenant, asp.net-core-1.0

I am migrating my multitenant application from Webapi to aspnet core. In webapi version I was using `TenantIdentificationStrategy` that identified tenants based on request path on `HttpContext`.

Moving to aspnet core, I am able to wire-up autofac successfully. I am not able to figure out how to wireup the tenant strategy. I tried injecting `IHttpContextAccessor` in `ConfigureServices` as

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

and my strategy looks like this

```
public class AssetClassIdentificationStrategy: ITenantIdentificationStrategy {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    public AssetClassIdentificationStrategy(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _accessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public bool TryIdentifyTenant(out object tenantId) {
        tenantId = null;
        var context = _accessor.HttpContext;
        if (context != null && context.Request != null )){
            var matchRegex = new Regex(@"\/[\d,\.,\w]*\/(\w*)\/.*");
            var match = matchRegex.Match(context.Request.Path.ToString());
            if (match.Success) {
                tenantId = match.Groups[1].Value.ToLower();
            }
        }
        return tenantId != null;
    }
}
```

What I am seeing is that `HttpContextAccessor` is being injected correctly, where as `HttpContext` within it always null. As a result of this none of the multitenant services are being resolved.

Looked around for samples, but couldn't find anything that fits the problem. There used to be a `RequestParameterTenantIdentificationStrategy` in Autofacv3 which is no longer supported. Appreciate any help with this.

**Edit**
Fixed issue with code and adding Startup.cs as requested.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CacheConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("Caching"),false);
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddTransient<ITenantIdentificationStrategy,AssetClassIdentificationStrategy>();

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Populate(services);
        builder.RegisterType<TenantInfo>().WithProperty("TenantName", "unknown").As<ITenantInfo>();

        var container = builder.Build();

        ITenantIdentificationStrategy tenantIdentificationStrategy;
        bool isMultiTenant = container.TryResolve(out tenantIdentificationStrategy);

        var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(tenantIdentificationStrategy, container);
        mtc.ConfigureTenant("pesonalLoans", b => {
            b.RegisterType<TenantInfo>().WithProperty("TenantName","pesonalLoans") .As<ITenantInfo>();
        });
        mtc.ConfigureTenant("retirement", b => {
            b.RegisterType<TenantInfo>().WithProperty("TenantName", "retirement").As<ITenantInfo>();
        });

        return mtc.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        LoggingConfig.Register(Configuration, loggerFactory);
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}


public class ValuesController : Controller {
    private ITenantInfo _tenant;
    public ValuesController(ITenantInfo tenant) {
        _tenant = tenant;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return  _tenant.TenantName;
    }
}


public interface ITenantInfo {
    string TenantName { get; set; }
}
public class TenantInfo: ITenantInfo
{
    public string TenantName { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit 3** project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Autofac": "4.0.0-rc2-240",
    "Autofac.Multitenant": "4.0.0-beta8-219",
    "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": "5.0.0-rc2-305061149",
    "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0-rc2-240",
    "System.Reflection": "4.1.0-rc2-24027",
    "System.Reflection.Primitives": "4.0.1-rc2-24027",
    "System.Reflection.Extensions": "4.0.1-rc2-24027",
    "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.1.0-rc2-24027",
    "System.Reflection.Emit": "4.0.1-rc2-24027",
    "System.Reflection.Context": "4.0.1-rc2-24027",
    "System.Reflection.DispatchProxy": "4.0.1-rc2-24027",
    "System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration": "4.0.1-rc2-24027",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Json": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your startup file?

Comment: I have attached the startup file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not currently a way to inject things into a tenant identification strategy because the strategy itself doesn't go through the DI pipeline.

`IHttpContextAccessor` is usually just backed with [`HttpContextAccessor`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/3a97a6bdfdcc3787bf4b68cecdf277588de5ee76/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/HttpContextAccessor.cs) which is a singleton anyway and acts by getting info from async/thread local context. You could just new-up your strategy with one of these directly when you're in startup:

`var strat = new MyStrategy(new HttpContextAccessor());`

Note that at the time the question was originally asked there was an issue with the way multitenancy interacted with the ASP.NET Core `IServiceProvider` system, which is to say, it didn't.

Since then, we've released [`4.0.0-rc3-309` for the `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/4.0.0-rc3-309) which remedies the issue.

The change is that **you need to update `ConfigureServices` to `return new AutofacServiceProvider(mtc);`** and no longer do `return mtc.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();`.

Comment: I tried this approach now and I found HttoContext in HttpContextAccessor is null. 

Another thing I found was, if I place a break point in TryIdentifyTenant in strategy the break-point doesnt hit for page each request. 

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't personally tried the new ASP.NET Core stuff with the multitenant support yet. I'm not sure what's up there, but chances are the current Core integration is doing something that bypasses multitenancy. I'll have to check it out. The context accessor thing should work, though.

Comment: I've added a comment to the overall Autofac [to do list for Core](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/594#issuecomment-229820297). We'll look at it.

Comment: Fixed in the latest release. Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This became to long for a comment.

First off your class is named `SampleIdentificationStrategy` but your constructor references `AssetClassIdentificationStrategy`. From this issue the project shouldnt even compile.

Next (as you havent provided a startup file) make sure you populating the registered services in AutoFac by calling the below code in the `ConfigureServices` method.

```
builder.Populate(services);
builder.Update(container);
```

Note this method *must* be run *after* you have registered all your services to the `IServiceCollection`

Next make sure you are not mixing framework versions. There are big differences between `RC2` `RC1`, `beta-x` etc. This was noted [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1346) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1257) on the GitHub issue logs.

Other than this we need to see your `startup.cs` file (notably extracts from the `ConfigureServices` method, your `project.json` file (notably the `frameworks` and `dependency` nodes).

Comment: I have added the statup file and project.json, please take a look