# Configuring Core 1.0 to target net45 and run IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'd appreciate help configuring my MVC applications correctly to target .NET 4.5 using the latest ASPNET Core 1.0 tooling.

I'm unable to get anything other than a  502.3 response from IISExpress after upgrading from Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6 RC to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0.

I'm guessing I'm missing some basic config here, but there is very little documentation on targeting .NET 4.5 using the Core tooling.

Help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Here's my project.json:

```
{
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "compile": {
        "exclude": [
            "wwwroot",
            "node_modules"
        ]
    }
},
"configurations": {
    "Development": {}
},
"dependencies": {
    "Autofac": "4.0.0-rc1-177",
    "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0-rc1-177",
    "AutofacSerilogIntegration": "1.0.12",
    "AutoMapper": "4.2.1",
    "MediaTypeMap": "2.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile": "2.1.0",
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen": "6.0.0-beta901",
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi": "6.0.0-beta901"
},
"frameworks": {
    "net451": {}
},
"publishOptions": {
    "exclude": [
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "include": [
        "Areas",
        "Views",
        "wwwroot",
        "appsettings.json",
        "web.config"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp" ]
},

"tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},
"userSecretsId": "asdf",
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"webroot": "wwwroot"
```

}

And here's my Main:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
        host.Run();
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using AutofacSerilogIntegration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Serilog;
using Swashbuckle.Swagger.Model;

namespace Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var contentRootPath = env.ContentRootPath;
            // Set up configuration sources.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(contentRootPath)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true);


        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
            builder.AddUserSecrets();
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
        GlobalVariables.WebRootPath = env.WebRootPath;

        var configSettings = new ConfigSettings(Configuration);
        string logPath = configSettings.LoggingConfiguration.Path;
        logPath = LoggingPathHelper.GetPath(logPath, env.WebRootPath);

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile(logPath)
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        Serilog.SerilogLoggerFactoryExtensions.AddSerilog(loggerFactory);
        appLifetime?.ApplicationStopped.Register(Log.CloseAndFlush);
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

            // For more details on creating database during deployment see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615859
            //CORE 1.0 upgrade: this doesn't appear to be used. Appears to be redundant to the work done in Identity project - asteffes
            //try {
            //    using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
            //        .CreateScope()) {
            //        serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>()
            //            .Database.Migrate();
            //    }
            //}
            //catch {
            //}
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();


        // Tell OWIN to use Cookies to save the Identity and other Claims information
        var cookieAuthenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true
        };
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieAuthenticationOptions);

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var options = new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            Authority = GlobalVariables.Settings.SecurityIdentityServerEndpointURI,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            Audience = GlobalVariables.Settings.SecurityIdentityServerEndpointURI + "resources",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true
        };




        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                "areaRoute",
                "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "default",
                "{controller=App}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        // Add Swagger support
        // https://damienbod.com/2015/12/13/asp-net-5-mvc-6-api-documentation-using-swagger/


        app.UseSwaggerUi();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var exceptionNotifierFilter = new ExceptionNotifierFilter();
        services.AddMvc(options => { options.Filters.Add(exceptionNotifierFilter); })
            // Make all results be camel-case
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                    new CustomCamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
                    new StringEnumConverter {CamelCaseText = true});
            });


        // Add Swagger support
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
        // https://damienbod.com/2015/12/13/asp-net-5-mvc-6-api-documentation-using-swagger/
        var pathToDoc = Configuration["Swagger:Path"];
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
        services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            var info = new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "API",
                Description = "API",
            };
            options.SingleApiVersion(info);
            options.IncludeXmlComments(pathToDoc);
            var addFileUploadParams = new AddFileUploadParams();
            options.OperationFilter<AddFileUploadParams>(addFileUploadParams);
            options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            //options.OperationFilter(new Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen.XmlComments.ApplyXmlActionComments(pathToDoc));
        });

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();

        var autofacContainer = RegisterAutofac(services, Configuration);
        var serviceProvider = autofacContainer.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();

        // Save the ConfigSetttings instance in the Service Provider so it can be used elsewhere in the application.
        // This is necessary because serviceProvider is no longer accessible from within the application.
        GlobalVariables.Settings = serviceProvider.GetService<ConfigSettings>();
        GlobalVariables.AutofacContainer = autofacContainer;
        GlobalServiceVariables.AutofacContainer = autofacContainer;

        InjectDependenciesInto(exceptionNotifierFilter, serviceProvider);

        // Return the ServiceProvider created above based on AutofacModule
        // NOTE:  This changes the return value of Configuration to IServiceProvider
        return serviceProvider;
    }


    private static void InjectDependenciesInto(ExceptionNotifierFilter exceptionNotifierFilter,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // Have to use setter injection since the instance had to be created earlier
        exceptionNotifierFilter.EmailService = serviceProvider.GetService<IEmailsService>();
        exceptionNotifierFilter.ConfigSettings = serviceProvider.GetService<ConfigSettings>();
        exceptionNotifierFilter.UserResolver = serviceProvider.GetService<IUserResolver>();
        exceptionNotifierFilter.ExceptionLogEntryRepository =
            serviceProvider.GetService<IEntityRepository<ExceptionLogEntry>>();
        exceptionNotifierFilter.CryptographyService = serviceProvider.GetService<ICryptographyService>();
    }

    private static IContainer RegisterAutofac(IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // We need to pass in the web assembly and the IServiceFacade so that Autofac can register them;
        // since web has a dependency on init, init cannot have a direct dependency back to web.
        var maxAutofacModule = new MaxAutofacModule(configuration);
        maxAutofacModule.IncludeServiceFacadeRegistrations(typeof(Startup).Assembly, typeof(IServiceFacade));
        builder.RegisterModule(maxAutofacModule);
        builder.Populate(services);

        var container = builder.Build();

        builder.RegisterLogger(Log.Logger);
        return container;
    }
}
```

}

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post your `Startup` class as well?

Comment: Added startup to the original post.

Comment: One critical missing component is the registration of the IHttpContextAccessor dependency injection mapping, mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111427/how-to-inject-ihttpcontextaccessor-into-autofac-tenantidentificationstrategy

I discovered this issue after using "dotnet run" on the console to locate errors. 

I'm now getting IISExpress runtime errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` into `Program.cs`, between `.UseKestrel()` and `.UseIISIntegration()`
2. Check your `web.config` in root (not `wwwroot`!) of your project, it must look [like this](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rtm.html?highlight=aspnetcoremodule#working-with-iis)

Comment: It was these changes in addition to the ones I mentioned above in my comment that helped me find a solution. For others, don't forget to start with "dotnet run" from the command line. I also wish in hindsight I had started with a new blank template and then transferred over existing code to the new template as opposed to upgrade existing projects. Good resources are Rick Strahl's blog posts and shanw wildermuth posts.